# DASK: Replace infinite (inf) values in single column

Tags: python, dataframe, dask

I have a dask dataframe in which I have a few `inf` values appearing. I wish to areplace these on a per column basis, because where inf exists I can replace with a value that is appropriate to the upper bounds that can be expected from that column.

I'm having some trouble understanding [the documentation](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/array-api.html#dask.array.isinf), or rather translating it into something I can use to replace infinite values.

What I have been trying is roughly around the below, replacing `inf` with `1000` - however the inf value seems to remain in place, unchanged.

Any advice on how to do this would be excellent. Because this is a huge dataframe (10m rows, 40 cols) I'd prefer to do it in a fashion that doesn't use lamba or loops- which the below should basically achieve, but doesn't.

`ddf['mycolumn'].replace(np.inf,1000)`

Comment: `ddf['mycolumn'].replace(np.inf,1000)` returns a pandas.Series and therefore its value is not being used. Try replacing to `ddf['mycolumn'] = ddf['mycolumn'].replace(np.inf,1000)`

Comment: @Enzo if you post this as an answer I'll mark it as correct

Comment: Just to avoid duplicate answers, you can mark @SultanOrazbayev's answer, thank you for the consideration

Comment: Have done. Thank you again.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @Enzo's comment, make sure you are assigning the replaced values back to the original column:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, np.inf], columns=['a'])
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)
ddf['a'] = ddf['a'].replace(np.inf, 1000)

# check results with: ddf.compute()
#         a
# 0     1.0
# 1     2.0
# 2  1000.0
```